# Same code ran on different PC but not working on this one

Tags: c

The task at hand is to calculate the yearly average temperature for each of the lakes, and the yearly average for all six lakes
put together.

Text needs to be read from the file below, when I saved it onto my desktop, I made sure to remove all the lines excluding the one's with actual data so I only have numbers on my text file, which begins

```
  Daily Lake Average Surface Water Temperature
                     From
 Great Lakes Surface Environmental Analysis maps

--------------------------------------------------------
                  Surf. Water Temp. (degrees C)

Year Day    Sup.   Mich.   Huron    Erie    Ont.  St.Clr
--------------------------------------------------------

2017 001    3.88    4.36    4.00    3.06    5.03    2.06
2017 002    3.46    4.36    3.98    3.05    5.01    2.12
2017 003    3.33    4.36    3.94    3.01    5.00    2.14
...etc
```

I have attached the code that I have tried, which worked at school but not on my personal computer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()

{
double line[365][8], sup, mich, huron, erie, ont, stclr, avesup, avemich, avehuron, aveerie, aveont, avestclr, ave;
int row, column;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        for(column=1;column<=8;column++)
            {
                fscanf(fp, "%lf", &line[row][column]);
            }
    }

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {

printf("%.0lf\t%.0lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\n", 
line[row][1], line[row][2], line[row][3], line[row][4], line[row][5], 
line[row][6], line[row][7], line[row][8]);
    }



for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        sup = sup + line[row][3];
    }
avesup = sup/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", avesup);

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        mich = mich + line[row][4];
    }
avemich = mich/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", avemich);

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        huron = huron + line[row][5];
    }
avehuron = huron/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", avehuron);

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        erie = erie + line[row][6];
    }
aveerie = mich/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", aveerie);

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        ont = ont + line[row][7];
    }
aveont = ont/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", aveont);

for(row=1;row<=365;row++)
    {
        stclr = stclr + line[row][8];
    }
avestclr = stclr/365;
printf("%.2lf\n", avestclr);

ave = avesup + avemich + avehuron + aveerie + aveont + avestclr;
printf("%.2lf", ave);


fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

It worked at school and averaged fine but now it is not working.

Comment: Define "didn't work" - what exactly does that mean? Do you get error messages?

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Please specify the behaviour you're expecting and the one you're actually getting

Comment: code comes out like this:

https://gyazo.com/89713f2c1bcbec1600cbd4cc84276a27

Comment: Hi arbazh, welcome to Stack Overflow! To be able to answer your question, we need to know what exactly "doesn't work" means - are you getting compilation errors, linker errors, runtime crashes, unexpected output, somethine else...? Please be more specific.

Comment: code comes out like this: https://gyazo.com/89713f2c1bcbec1600cbd4cc84276a27

rather, i want it to appear as the table linked and then simply print the averages underneath the table

Comment: you use invalid array indexes, see my answer

Comment: please do not post links to screen shots.  Rather, copy/paste the data into the question, itself.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Don't indent the braces from the surrounding code.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 365, 8.   'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names.  Then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT:  it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  I.E. `#include <math.h>`   Suggest removing that statement.

Comment: regarding: `for(column=1;column<= MAX_LINES ;column++)` and similar statements:  1) insert appropriate horizontal spacing for readability  2) in C, the range of valid indexes into an array are 0...(number of elements in array -1)  So these kinds of statements will access beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behavior (and possibly a seg fault event)

Comment: OT: regarding: `fscanf(fp, "%lf", &line[row][column]);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  `if( fscanf(fp, "%lf", &line[row][column]) != 1) { // handle error }`

Comment: The first two entries on each line in the input file are not `doubles`  the first is an integer and the second is an octal number.  So reading those with a "%f" will not result in the expected values

Comment: OT:  why the magic number 365?  This greatly limits the ability of the program to handle any other file length.  Suggest, at least, perform an initial pass through the input file, just counting the number of rows (fgets() in a loop with a loop counter would work) so you have the actual number of lines.  Then declare the `line[][]` array using that 'corrected' value

Comment: Note:  it did not actually 'work' on the 'school' computer.  The resultant 'average' values would be incorrect

Comment: OT: regarding: `fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call: `perror( "fopen to read data.txt failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `line[row][1], line[row][2], line[row][3], line[row][4], line[row][5], 
line[row][6], line[row][7], line[row][8]);`   The indexes are all 1 too high.  In C, the data would be sequential in memory.  So that last parameter: `line[row][8])`  would be accessing the first parameter of the next row (the date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in all the

> for (row=1;row<=365;row++)

the range of index is invalid, must be

```
for (row=0;row<365;row++)
```

and of course same problem in

> ```
> for(column=1;column<=8;column++)
> ```

whose must be

```
for(column=0;column<8;column++)
```

Also

> ```
>   printf("%.0lf\t%.0lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\n",
>          line[row][1], line[row][2], line[row][3], line[row][4], line[row][5], 
>          line[row][6], line[row][7], line[row][8]);
> ```

must be

```
  printf("%.0lf\t%.0lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\t%.2lf\n",
         line[row][0], line[row][1], line[row][2], line[row][3], line[row][4], 
         line[row][5], line[row][6], line[row][7]);
```

The behavior when you go out of an array is undefined, this is why it (seems) to work on some platforms and not on others

In an array the indexes start at 0, not at 1

Comment: Thank you, 

I was aware that by default they started at 0 but I thought you could manipulate the code in order to get them to start at 1.

Comment: One more question, my code is not terminating randomly now but the format of the output is incorrect.

https://gyazo.com/a5e7a63b58e730f80121c9683d4849b2

I want the output to display as in the notepad file, it seems as if the first value is pushed all the way to the right but I want it at the left.

I feel like it has something to do with the code prior to the averaging.

Comment: @arbazh it is also needed to modify the _printf args like `line[row][1]` to bo `line[row][0]` etc, I edited my answer, look again at it

Comment: I have edited it but it still is shifting the year all the way to the far right rather than on the left which is also messing up the averages.

Comment: @arbazh you missed to do at least a change, it is not possible to have the year in two consecutive cells, did you look at my answer ? not only `line[row][1]` is changed

Comment: yes I have changed all the years going from 0-7. It still is putting the year all the way to the right.

Comment: @arbazh do you really have "Daily Lake Average Surface Water Temperature" etc in data.txt ? if yes you need to bypass the header lines

Comment: No I have removed it, I have removed all text from that file and it is simply numbers left in that text file. For example, the last line of the file should output as follows:

2017 365    2.62    3.14    2.30    1.39    3.45    0.21

Instead it is outputting:

365 2.62 3.14 2.30 1.39 3.45 0.21 and then 2017

Comment: @arbazh if you did all the corrections and the file is like you say the year is on the last column, you missed something. Can you put the new version of the code and data.txt somewhere ot allow me to look at them ?

Comment: Hey Bruno,

Thanks for the help, I have gone on my laptop and the code has worked even though it's the exact same code, I even took out the averaging part on my personal computer and it still ran the averaging code so I think it must have been some type of problem with the IDE on my personal computer.

Comment: for me the result is correct, warning you open "temp.txt" but the file is "data.txt, are you sure you read the right file  ?

Comment: @arbazh ok fine